# Как можно изменить тип данных float на int?

Tags: python, pandas

[image: python_screen]
хотелось бы чтобы тип столбца focal_depth поменялось на инт.  С помощью astype()  не получится(

Comment: текст лучше прилагать в виде текста, а не картинки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать если в данном столбце отсутствуют NaN значения:

```
quake_data.Focal_depth = quake_data.Focal_depth.astype(np.int32)
```

Если же в данном столбце присутствует хотя бы одно значение NaN или inf, то тип столбца не изменится и останется float.

Чтобы проверить число строк с нулевым значением:

```
quake_data.Focal_depth.isna().any().sum()
```

Чтобы вывести все строки, в которых Focal_depth нулевой:

```
quake_data[quake_data.Focal_depth.isna()]
```

PS Судя по выводу ‘.info()’ у вас в одной строке нулевое значение во всех полях.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Посоедняя строка датасета был состовлее из na. Я удалил их с помощью функции dropna(). И все сработало!